# use of enum in retrofit response with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

I am building an app with retrofit and I have a data class to represent the model.

```
data class RetrofitModel(
    @SerializedName("lock_status") val lockStatus: LockStatus,
    @SerializedName("door_status") val doorStatus: DoorStatus,
)

@Keep
enum class LockStatus(status: String) {
    Unlocked("Unlocked"),
    Locked("Locked")
}

@Keep
enum class DoorStatus(status: String) {
    DoorOpen("door_open"),
    DoorClose("close")
}
```

Overall the the code works fine but when I try later to extract the value of the DoorStatus class, it doesn't work for the `door_open`

if I do a `lockStatus.name` I will get `Unlocked` or `Locked` depending on the status received but for `doorStatus.name` I got `close` but if the status is `door_open` I have a null value.

As soon as `_` is there, it's not working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why its not working with underscore.Because json serialization/deserialization works for multiple naming styles like underscrore/camelcase ...

Several things you can try.

1. Adding serializedName annotation to the enum values.

```
enum class DoorStatus(status: String) {
    @SerializedName("door_open")
    DoorOpen("door_open"),
    @SerializedName("close")
    DoorClose("close")
}
```

2. Camel casing the value name. I think Usually it would detect the field even its in different naming convention with same name. So `door_open` will be mapped to `doorOpen`.

   ```
   enum class DoorStatus(status: String) {
    DoorOpen("doorOpen"),
    DoorClose("close")
   }
   ```